# What blocking object to use?

Tags: java, multithreading, blocking

I need a blocking object for triggering some events.
A (single) Consumer should wait for a trigger to occur. Then it does some stuff. Then it again waits for a trigger. 
The triggers are activated by multiple different threads (Producers). But the Producers do not produce any data. The semantic meaning of such a trigger is: "The Consumer has to do something" (for example recalculate some values, because the underlying data changed). 
That means even if the trigger is activated multiple times, it should appear to the Consumer as a single trigger.

I thought about using a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) or an [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html), but they don't seem appropriate.

This is the trigger construct I'd like to use:

```
public class Trigger{
  private final MagicBlockingObject blockingLatch;

  public void trigger(){
     //activate the blockingLatch, so that a call to waitForTrigger() returns
  } 

  public void waitForTrigger(){
    //read from the blockingLatch. This should block until trigger() is called.
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what to use for the `MagicBlockingObject`?

A `BlockingQueue` seems appropriate, but I did not find a way to restrict it to a single content object without blocking the Producers, if the Queue is already filled.

Comment: I think you are looking for `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition`

Comment: Is synchronized to simple for this case?

Comment: You do simple with synchonize and wait(), notify() calls.

Comment: "if the trigger is activated multiple times, it should appear to the Consumer as a single trigger" - this is very dangerous design decision, as some activations are ignored. You have to think twice of the way/time the trigger is cleared by the consumer, because it influences which activations are ignored.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I don't think so. Where do you see the problem? The trigger isn't cleared by the consumer manually, but only consumed. It doesn't matter whether 1 or 10 producers have activated the trigger until the consumer is notified. Do you see any problems in Duncan Jones solution?

Comment: Looks like Duncan's solution is ok for your problem. However, you said that Consumer have to recalculate some data, which are changed somehow. Consumer must synchronize on that data anyway, why not to combine that synchronization with triggering event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this with an `ArrayBlockingQueue` with a capacity of one:

```
public class Trigger{
  private final ArrayBlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);

  public void trigger(){
     queue.offer("foo");
  } 

  public void waitForTrigger(){
    queue.take();
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the best solution. I didn't think about using `offer()`. Since `offer()` doesn't block the producer it works like I want.

Comment: You can easily avoid to create new objects, e.g. `Queue<String>` + `offer("foo")` or use existing Objects like `Boolean.TRUE` (that's what [`Collections.newSetFromMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap%28java.util.Map%29) does)

Comment: @zapl Good idea, I've stolen your string suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

What is problem with simple solution like this:

```
public class Trigger {
    private final Object blockingLatch = new Object();

    public void trigger() {
        //activate the blockingLatch, so that a call to waitForTrigger() returns
        synchronized(blockingLatch){
            blockingLatch.notify();
        }
    }

    public void waitForTrigger() throws InterruptedException {
        //read from the blockingLatch. This should block until trigger() is called.
        synchronized(blockingLatch){
            blockingLatch.wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer will call waitForTrigger() and will block till producer have not called trigger(). If consumer is not blocked then producer calling trigger() will not affect anything.

Comment: Of course, you are right. I didn't think about the simple wait()/notify(). Thanks that helps. It seems that even an ArrayBlockingQueue would work when using the [offer()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#offer(E)) method, since it does not block.

Comment: @radlan, is this you need()?

Comment: Argh! It seems I wasn't right about wait()/notify(). What if a Producer calls trigger(), but no Consumer has called waitForTrigger() yet?

Comment: Then nothing will happen. Simply producer will complete method. But if consumer has called blockingLatch.wait() then consumer will get notified and will unblock.

Comment: Yep. That's the problem. :-) The suggestion from Duncan Jones is therefore more appropriate in my case.

Comment: Consumer will get notification only after it has called wait(). But if you need to queue next notification while consumer is processing previous notification, then that answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.concurrent` has a lot of nice utilities. `wait` and `notify` should be considered obsolete.

If I understand your problem you could try using a `Semaphore`

```
public class Blocking {
    private final Semaphore openTasks = new Semaphore(0);
    public void addTask() {
        // add 1
        openTasks.release();
    }
    public void takeAllTasks() throws InterruptedException {
        int immediately = openTasks.drainPermits();
        if (immediately > 0) {
            // there was a task, no need to wait
            return;
        }
        // wait for task
        openTasks.acquire();
        // ensure we leave this method without leaving permits
        openTasks.drainPermits()
    }
}
```

An unlimitted amount of producers can add "permits" to the semaphore and your consumer just takes them all or waits for at least one to appear.

Comment: Although your answer seems correct, I accepted the one from Duncan Jones, since it has a bit more easier code. But thanks to you, too. It may work as well.

Comment: @radlan `wait` / `notify` has some problems. For example when your consumer is not currently in `waitForTrigger`, every `notify` that happens in that time just goes poof because nothing is waiting for them. That can be a desired property but it is usually a problem.

Comment: @radlan oops, forget what I said, nice solution.

Comment: If several producers call `addTask()` before `openTasks.acquire()` executes (but after the `drainPermits()`) call, then `takeAllTasks()` would return immediately upon next call. I'm not sure if that would be desired behaviour.

Comment: @DuncanJones Oh, right, that's not good. Adding another `drainPermits` at the end should fix that.